# How is .format(self=self) used?

Tags: python, class

I saw a piece of code that was like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,color,mileage):
        self.color = color
        self.mileage = mileage

    def __str__(self):
        return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=self)

my_car = Car('blue', 13585)
print(my_car)
```

How does the self=self that is used in the str method work?

Comment: It means that where `self` occurs inside `{}` in the format string, it refers to object referenced by the `self` variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
def __str__(self):
        return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=self)
```

The first `self` in `self=self` refers to what the `format` function will change in your string. For example, it could also be

```
'a {obj.color} car'.format(obj=self)
```

The left-hand side `self` in `self=self` refers to the actual value that will be input. In this case, the object passed as argument. In other words, it could also be

```
def __str__(obj):
        return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=obj)
```

Thus, for an overall view, you have

```
def __str__(value_passed):
        return 'a {value_to_change.color} car'.format(value_to_change=value_passed)
```

---

*Now why to use `self`?*

It is just a convention used in python programming. Python passes to its instance methods automatically an object that is a pointer to itself. Can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) for further info

Answer (score 1):

`self` is being used in two separate contexts; one as a local variable in the method, and the other as an identifier in the format string. You could rename either one or both and get the same result:

```
return "a {c.color} car".format(c=self)
```

or

```
def __str__(foo):
    return "a {self.color} car".format(self=foo)
```

or even

```
def __str__(foo):
    return "a {bar.color} car".format(bar=foo)
```

My preference would be for the first alternative of the three, as there's no good reason to violate the convention that the first parameter to an instance method be named `self`.

Answer (score 0):

The first `self` (left of the `=` sign) refers to the self string in `'a {self.color} car'` (you can call it like you want).`

The second `self` (right of the `=` sign) refers to the first argument of the `__str__()` method, which is always a reference to the current instance of the class. In your example, this will be replaced by `my_car`.

Comment: *The second self (right of the = sign) is a Python keyword* - it's not a keyword... it's just a name which is by convention `self` - it could be anything a developer chooses...